# Form submit, download response as XLSX, and notify

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I have the following form:

```
<form id='report-inputs' method='post' action='generate.php'>
<!-- inputs -->
</form>
```

The result of `generate.php` is a generated Excel document (.xlsx):

```
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_DATA['title'].'.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

**The most important thing to know here is that this works flawlessly as-is.** Now I am quite aware that I can't use jQuery to `$.post` this form and download the results. That brings me to my actual question:

How would I best implement a "waiting" dialog of some kind? The form takes about 30 seconds to complete and get your file, and just the normal browser spinner isn't very useful. I certainly know how to stand up an animated GIF or a dialog that says "Working", but how do I tell the browser to bring it down?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect when browser receives file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)

Comment: What takes time? Downloading the file or generating it?

Comment: Read: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx It has a clever technique where you have the PHP set a cookie. Block the UI using the jQuery blockUI plugin when the form is submitted. Then, have JavaScript check every second to see if the cookie exists. If it does the download has completed and you can unblock the UI.

Comment: @Adam Brilliant. Worked right out of the gate.